# netbeans cannot open shared library during RUN comm

Tags: netbeans

everything worked fine but I've just tried to run my CUDA programs on Linux Ubuntu 12.10 in NetBeans and I get error:

> dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/my_cuda_1: error while loading shared
>   libraries: libcudart.so.5.0: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory
>
> RUN FAILED (exit value 127, total time: 191ms)

the projects can build: compile + link without problems, I can also run it from commandline but if I try run it from NetBeans I get this error.
I was able to run it few minutes ago, what might happened?

I have added file my_lib to ld.so.conf.d containing such text:

> > /usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64:/lib
> >     /usr/lib
> >     /usr/lib64

can it be a link issue libcudart.so.5.0 -> licudart.so?
there are two libs in cuda/lib libcudart.so.5.0 (link) and libcudart.so (link) and libcudart.so.5.0.35 (shared lib)
why it complains about .so.5.0? mayve link like: 
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3 /usr/lib/libglut.so 
is necessary

it is related to link to shared library I think

> root@comp:# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib::/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64:/lib

isn't this :: a problem? seems that No because I changed this and still same error. I specify PATHS, I run ldconfig, I put exports in the .bashrc, still nothing.
the reason is that I cannot load these libraries if program is started from NetBeans GUI, however I start NetBeans as root always

Comment: It's an environment issue.  Netbeans is not preserving the value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` when it is running your code. You might try `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from the commandline to see how it is set, then figure out how to have netbeans specify that when running your code.

Comment: This question is all about NetBeans and totally unrelated to CUDA. I am removing the CUDA tag.

Comment: how this is possible that it worked 10 minutes ago? I was building and runnung this code in netbeans since 1 month and suddenly something has been deleted?

Comment: @Robert Crovella I go to project options->linker and add this lib, so definitly it has it

Comment: It's not a linker issue.  It's a *runtime environment issue*.  Did you run `ldconfig` (and log out/log back in) after modifying things in ld.so.conf.d ?

Comment: it has worked for 1 month, now I removed changed made 40 minutes ago so it is as it was and don't work

Comment: but I am talking about link like this: sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3 /usr/lib/libglut.so

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add to the Project -> Properties -> Run -> Environment

> Name: LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>
> Value:
>   $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64:/lib

Thank you all. I don't know what happened before as it worked just fine.

Comment: I had this same problem with Netbeans.  I think the correct solution is to add LD_LIBRARY_PATH to  contain what you need and then reboot or do whatever is necessary to get your system to add LD_LIBRARY_PATH (mentioned above).  You will immediately run into a new problem if you dont do that:  If you don't, then when you go to run your compiled executable from the command line, it will fail.  LD_LIBRARY_PATH, correctly set, should resolve both issues.